# MySQL WHERE equals BIGINT does not work

Tags: mysql

I have a very-very strange situation. One and the same query works differently on different servers, but on the very same database. So, this is the query

```
SELECT  attr_83052_ FROM object_83038_ WHERE attr_83051_ = 2 AND attr_83052_ = 22
```

On the **first** server (MySQL version 5.6.24) it returns values - I see rows with data. On the **second** server (MySQL version 5.6.26), it does not return anything. However, if I run this:

```
SELECT  attr_83052_ FROM object_83038_ WHERE attr_83051_ = 2
```

on the **second** server, I see a lot of rows which have in column `attr_83052_` values `22`. I clearly see it with my own eyes, that indeed there is some data that corresponds to condition `attr_83051_ = 2 AND attr_83052_ = 22`. However, even more interesting that if I run this on the second **server** :

```
SELECT  attr_83051_, attr_83052_ FROM object_83038_  
WHERE attr_83051_ = 2 
AND attr_83052_ IN (
    SELECT attr_83052_ FROM object_83038_ where attr_83052_ > 21 AND 
    attr_83052_ < 23 
)
```

then it returns data. It all looks like insane behaviour of MySQL. How it all can be true??? Thanks!

Comment: It seems some bugfix side effect that generate another bug. Just to be sure! The table structure on both servers are the same right  (and data)?

Comment: One and the same schema. Besides, I took backup from the **second** server and deployed this database on the **first** server. So, it is even more interesting

Comment: Then this is most probably a side effect in a bugfix since the  difference is only on minor version number (24 -> 26). You should open an issue on MySQL issue tracker.

Comment: And by the way, if I instead do it like so `WHERE CAST(attr_83051_ AS UNSIGNED) = 2` then it works. But in schema this field is simply `bigint not null default 0`

Comment: By the way, this field `attr_83052_` had an index. I dropped it and it started to work.

Comment: It is an obvious bug in `MySQL`. I knew that it is hardly possible to find a database worse than `MySQL`. But I could not even expect, that it so-so bad. I now see, that you cannot trust to `MySQL`

Comment: Well, the community is always trying to do their best on helping us to use a free software. I don't think that MySQL is untrustful! The community is there just exactly for that! They help us we help then to get better. Developing software as long as I do (since 94) there are bugs that are just impossible to trace. It end up with the user. In that case, us! So you really should open an issue there so they can fix it as soon as possible so others don't go into the same problem as you!

Comment: Thank you for sharing  your thoughts. Personally, I have dozens of arguments against using MySQL in production, and the list becomes larger and larger every day.